# Does sql server compact still limit to 4gb

Tags: sql-server-ce

I saw in forums that the limit for an SQL Server compact database is 4gb. Does anyone know if this limit has been increased yet, sql server express was recently expanded to 10GB..

Can anyone point me to the official source for this limit?

Comment: It's still 4GB in 4.0, but I'm having a hard time finding official docs confirming it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The limit for a SQL Server Compact database is 4GB.

Refs:

- [Will the SQL Compact 4.0 limited to 4GB?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/7657710c-a27d-4702-8155-e6886957465a)
- [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx)
- [Wiki: SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)

Surprisingly, it's not on this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140.aspx) listing differences between SQL Server Compact 3.5, compared with SQL Server.

Here are the [maximum size limitations for several database objects defined in Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172451.aspx)

Update (thanks @ErikEJ): Here is the corresponding page for [SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172451%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Here is the link for 4.0 regarding size limitations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172451(v=SQL.110).aspx

Comment: For example, it is not possible to create a BitCoin client using SQL Server Compact Edition.