# Best way to export SQL Server database to sqlite (or SQL Server Compact)

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-ce

Do someone know what would be the best way to transform a big SQL Server database to sqlite or SQL Server compact ?

SQL Server database should be around 50-70Gb.

There are some examples on internet (script schema) but I didn't find anything concluding about data.

Comment: You seriously want to store that kind of data into a single file and a single-user, file-based database system??

Comment: Max db size on SQL Compact is 4 GB.. And 50 GB with SQLite is simply not feasible

Comment: It's going to be hard.  Max size for a sql compact db is 4gb. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524197/does-sql-server-compact-still-limit-to-4gb

Comment: My problem is : I must send an offline app who read a database this size. Atm, I use vmware portable with windows+sql server embedded on an external drive. I would like to remove vmware (because of windows+SQL), so I thought about sqlite/sql compact. If you have any other idea...

Comment: According to this message [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998/how-scalable-is-sqlite#comment230095_66724), reading on a 50GB sqlite file is not a problem and that's exactly what I would like to do.

Comment: But the stated problem is 50-70GB - not exactly 50GB.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use my Exportsqlce tool to create .sql files in sqlite format from a SQL Server database. Then run them using sqlite3.exe

Download command line tools from https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/releases/tag/3.5.2

```
Export2SQLCE.exe "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True" Northwind.sql sqlite
```

Good luck!

(I also have SSMS and VS extensions that allow you to do this from a GUI)

Comment: I'm going to test this today.I'll mark my question as answered if it works.

Comment: After some tests. I've done it and reading from sqlite database is very fast. Thank you :)

Comment: This project moved to GitHub: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox probably should update answer

Comment: Worked painless with the SSMS Extension. Great great work.

Comment: @jjxtra ude the GUI tool to do that

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this software from Code Project:

[Convert SQL Server DB to SQLite DB](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB)

It connects with your SQL Server and opens Databases to select and select file destination
[image: Convert SQL Server To SQLite]

Answer (score 1):

I just did this too with SqlCeToolbox, actually through the SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) gui — [Export my SQL db to SQLite db in SSMS · Issue #327 · ErikEJ_SqlCeToolbox · GitHub](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/issues/327). But it made over 100 .sql script files I had to pipe to sqlite3.

```
# powershell
dir *.sql | sort name | % { "$_"; cat $_ | sqlite3 newdatabase.db }
```

It worked except for 3 parse errors, but I only lost 3 rows. Somehow directly making the sqlite db failed.

By the way, searching the script file dump is a create way to search every table.  [Search Sqlite Database - All Tables and Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514509/search-sqlite-database-all-tables-and-columns/65373519#65373519)

```
sqlite3 database.db .dump | select-string whatever

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(0,0,0,'whatever',0);
```